# compile node.js appear "NameError: global name 'file' is not defined"

Tags: node.js

I have python2 and python3,I run ./configure and it works.But I run make,

```
make -C out BUILDTYPE=Release V=1

make[1]: Entering directory `/home/colin4124/MyProgram/node/out'
  LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/colin4124/MyProgram/node/out/Release/lib.host:/home/colin4124/MyProgra>m/node/out/Release/lib.target:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH; export LD_LIBRARY_PATH; cd ../deps/v8/tools/gyp; mkdir -p /home/colin4124/MyProgram/node/out/Release/obj/gen; python ../../tools/gen-postmortem-metadata.py "/home/colin4124/MyProgram/node/out/Release/obj/gen/debug-support.cc" ../../src/objects.h ../../src/objects-inl.h
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "../../tools/gen-postmortem-metadata.py", line 479, in 
    emit_config();
  File "../../tools/gen-postmortem-metadata.py", line 432, in emit_config
    out = file(sys.argv[1], 'w');
NameError: global name 'file' is not defined
make[1]: *** [/home/colin4124/MyProgram/node/out/Release/obj/gen/debug-support.cc] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/colin4124/MyProgram/node/out'
make: *** [node] Error 2
```

How I can solve it,Think you!!

Comment: I have solve it。Because run "python" is run "python3" ,So I set run "python" is run "python3 . https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Python

Answer (score 3):

It looks like your default Python is 3.x, but the Node build scripts require Python 2.x.

According to [these instructions](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installation) you can fix it by setting the `PYTHON` environment variable to point to your Python 2 executable:

```
export PYTHON=`which python2`
```

Comment: Make sure you run `make distclean` to start a fresh build. Also, it assumes your Python 2.x executable is called `python2`, that might be different in your setup.

Comment: I don’t think so.Because I set python2 to python,it means when I run python,it would run python2

Comment: `file()` not being defined suggests that the script is being run with Python 3.

Comment: I have set it by the way of your anwer,but script still is being run with Python 3,how can I do next?

Comment: What does `python -V` say? If it says it's Python 2.x, perhaps try and remove the Node source directory completely and unpack the source archive to start completely fresh again.

Comment: My email is colin4124@gmail.com .Can you help me by Email?Thinks very much!

Answer (score 0):

It's because your default `python` is `python3.x`. Node.js recommend `python2.6`/`python2.7` to compile the source.

Try to check your `python` command via:

```
ls -l /usr/bin/python
```

it will show `lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Apr  3 15:46 /usr/bin/python -> python3`

To make `python2.7` as the default `python` command use:

```
sudo ln -sf `which python2.7` `which python`
ls -l /usr/bin/python
```

now it should be `lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Apr  3 15:46 /usr/bin/python -> python2.7`